# What are the minimum requirements for a processor so that a C compiler can be written for it?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I'm curious about the absolute minimum instructions that a processor should support so that a standard C compiler can be written targeted towards it. What are those requirements?

Comment: This one might be better at the Software Engineering site...

Comment: You know how a single-tape Turing machine works, yes? That's how much the CPU needs to be able to do. It's not a lot, I can tell you.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi Just for fun I've googled "C to Turing Machine compiler". It is yielding results.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I'm pretty sure that's not nearly enough. As a trivial example you won't be able to implement file i/o on a Turing Machine (though admittedly that's related to the CPU in only in so far that the CPU must have some sort of mechanism to interact with other hardware) - or time-related functions (which'd require the CPU to have a clock). I'd also expect the C standard to have some time-complexity requirements (such as random access being O(1)) that a Turing machine couldn't possibly meet.

Comment: @sepp2k The question here is about the processor, not the full-blown computer. You can add additional tape readers/writers as peripherals. And I don't think C standard has any requirements of time/space complexities..

Comment: @sepp2k file i/o is just a (special) case of reading from and writing to the tape. The steps of the Turing machine are discrete, hence it has a "clock" (yepp, it's a stretch, admitted). I don't know about time-complexity requirements in the standard. You need random access but the Turing machine can emulate that. Although the hidden constant in O(1) might get quite large.

Comment: @sepp2k Of course you can implement file I/O on a turing machine. The C standard doesn't say anything about the contents of files and how persistent they need to be. Time functions are allowed to fail on machines that don't support time (there are embedded systems without time). Actually file I/O is allowed to fail too. C doesn't have any big-O requirements as far as I know.

Comment: You might think that the processor needs to have more than an 8 bit address bus - 256 bytes of memory isn't enough to load a C compiler.  Well, if it is like the Apple 2 with banked memory I guess you could use overlays (the same way that MSDOS used to) and get more but it would still be tricky.  Like this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11805/reducing-the-memory-address-bus-by-adding-banks/11918

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is surprisingly simple. Any [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) machine can emulate any other Turing complete machine, machines that can have a C complier written for them are Turing complete, so they can be emulated by any Turing machine.

I/O from the C standard is quite vague so it doesn't need to be persistent, visible from outside or even do anything other than return errors, so that's not a requirement. Same goes for the time-related functions (I haven't looked at all of them, maybe there's an exception).

So in theory you can have a [single instruction computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer) that is powerful enough for C. Same goes for most other programming languages, btw. Not very useful without I/O, but it is enough.

Strictly speaking real physical computers are not Turing complete since they don't have infinte memory, but they are close enough that we squint and pretend it's the same thing.

Comment: that one instruction set computer article is awesome.

Comment: well you could argue that you cannot observe it's not a real Turing complete machine until you get an out of memory error.